# Best Practices with Validation and Asp.net Mvc 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

I been reading pro asp.net mvc 2.0 framework and I am a bit confused what I should use for my validation, where it should go and how to make sure I don't have to keep writing the same code.

My sites tend to be almost all ajax with jquery. So what I usually did was have jquery.validate for my client side and then on the server side have some checks again. If it would fail on the server side or if I had a validation rule I could not test on the client side then I would return the error messages.

A couple things suck with this way. First I have to make sure that the error messages are the same on the client side and server side. So I will always have 2 duplicate messages.

So if I misspell a word I got to make sure I remember to change it in 2 places. Second it hard to return the server side errors(most of my sites are almost all ajax) so what I did was I always had to check for a flag.

```
$.post('Create',{'test',test},function(response)
{
    if(response.IsValid == false) 
    {
        // check other json parameters to get all error msgs
        // add them to some div container and display to user.
    }
    else
     {
       // show success msg.
     } 
}):
```

I was looking at data annotations but I am not sure if they will help me since I am using ajax posts.

Will the client side code still show up if you click a button that is hooked up to an ajax post?

I am also guessing the server side messages will never be shown since does it not depend on looking for the html validation helpers that need a full page render?

I also find them pretty limiting. I know you can write your own but that seems to be alot to write(server side and client side code) especially since I would have to write basically everything jquery validate offers.

Is there library out there that is activity updated that allows you to use data annotations with jquery.validate(including remote that jquery.validate)?

Finally I don't know where this code should go. The author of the book sort of confused me.

He has

```
 public class Appointment
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")] [StringLength(50)]
        public string ClientName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)] [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose a date")]
        public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
    }
```

He has basic validation in what seems to be a veiw model. I understand this but what confused me is then in a service class he does basic validation again and business validation.

```
namespace BookingsExample.Domain.Services
{
    public class AppointmentService
    {
        public static void CreateAppointment(Appointment appt)
        {
            EnsureValidForCreation(appt);
            // To do: Now save the appointment to a database or wherever
        }

        private static void EnsureValidForCreation(Appointment appt)
        {
            var errors = new RulesException<Appointment>();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appt.ClientName))
                errors.ErrorFor(x => x.ClientName, "Please specify a name");

            if (appt.AppointmentDate < DateTime.Now.Date)
                errors.ErrorFor(x => x.AppointmentDate, "Can't book in the past");
            else if ((appt.AppointmentDate - DateTime.Now.Date).TotalDays > 7)
                errors.ErrorFor(x => x.AppointmentDate, "Can't book more than a week in advance");

            if (appt.ClientName == "Steve" && appt.AppointmentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                errors.ErrorForModel("Steve can't book on weekends");

            if (errors.Errors.Any())
                throw errors;
        }
    }
}
```

> Just because your model layer enforces
>   its own rules doesn't mean you have to
>   stop using ASP.NET MVC's built-in
>   validation support. I find it helpful
>   to think of ASP.NET MVC's validation
>   mechanism as a useful first line of
>   defense that is especially good at
>   generating a client-side validation
>   script with virtually no work. It fits
>   in neatly with the view model pattern
>   (i.e., having simple view-specific
>   models that exist only to transfer
>   data between controllers and views and
>   do not hold business logic): each view
>   model class can use Data Annotations
>   attributes to configure client-side
>   validation.
>
> But still, your domain layer shouldn't
>   trust your UI layer to enforce
>   business rules. The real enforcement
>   code has to go into the domain using
>   some technique like the one you've
>   just seen. *

- This is from the pro asp.net mvc 2.0 framework book chapter 12.

I can understand sort of why he does this so he can take the service layer and use it in different projects(ie you have some mobile application of your site and you need to use the same business logic).

However it looks kinda redundant that he is writing some of the same messages in 2 places and now he has to update the message in 2 places.  I am also not sure why he does not trust the "UI" to do the validation because it is being tested on the server side and that should be safe.

So won't it be just better to have it all in the service layer then? Or is it better to keep simple required fields in the view models for validation?

Comment: The Controller-level validation is indeed redundant and (imo) completely silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data annotations are the best solution to validate your objects on the server. You can validate them in code behind/controllers, service layer or data access layer.

Unfortunately there is not an out of the box solution to integrate data annotations and jquery.validate, so you will have to use some custom validation code in client script. If you want to have centralized validation, then you can make ajax calls to a validation service (json) that would validate your Appointment object on the server via Data annotations and return a json result to the client. The response can be a simple boolean value or a more complex object that you can use to build your UI display.

Comment: +1 for the head up now can you also provide some urls or references for us to get started with this approach to integrate "Data Annotations" with jQuery validation and AJAX.